# cipher.doFinal(...) fails while cipher.update(...) succeeds

Tags: java, encryption, aes, block-cipher

I am trying to decrypt a byte array using the following code. I left out exception handling and other practices for brevity:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
byte[] key = getKey(); \\Assume it is implemented.
byte[] iv = getIv(); \\Assume it is implemented;
SecretKeySpec sc = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sc, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
byte[] encrypted = getBytesFromFile(); \*Assume it is implemented. Simply reads bytes from a binary file into a byte array and returns them as are.*\
byte[] clear = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(encrypted.length)];
int processed = cipher.doFinal(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length, clear, 0);
```

**Note: PKCS7Padding is not supported natively in Java, but I did get it to work by adding the securtiy BouncyCastleProvider. For the sake of argument, PKCS5Padding has the same issue.**

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
```

**The problem:**

doFinal throws throws a **BadPaddingException: pad block corrupt**. However, If I replace *doFinal* with *update*, that is:

```
int processed = cipher.update(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length, clear, 0);
```

It works perfectly. The result is as expected.

Can some please help me understand what the difference is and how I can make doFinal work? Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing the encryption, best bet is that indeed the padding is incorrect. To check this decrypt without `PKCS7Padding` and you will be able to see the padding and determine if it is correct.

The error shows up in `doFinal` because that is where the padding is checked and removed if correct.

Do that and put a he dump of the decrypted data (hex because the padding will be bytes in the range 0x01 - 0x10.

Comment: The thing was only some of them had the padding. So when I moved to NoPadding and handled it manually everything worked just fine.Thanks!!!